# Handle Actions with Controllers Challenge

Tags: lightning-aura-components, trailhead

I'm Having some trouble with this unit. My code is as below and the problem is that I get an error when I click on the Checkbox:

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'Packed__c' of null]
>   Failing descriptor: {markup://lightning:input}

Or on the button

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
>   Action failed: c:campingListItem$controller$packItem [Cannot read property 'Packed__c' of null]
>   Failing descriptor: {c:campingListItem$controller$packItem}

Another minor issue is that next to my checkbox there are the words *ActiveInactive*

campingListItem.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c"  required="false"/>
  <p>{!v.item.Name}</p>
    <p>  
       <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Price__c}" style="currency"/>
    </p>
    <p>  
       <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}"/>
    </p>

 <lightning:input type="toggle" label = "Packed?" 
                   checked="{!v.item.Packed__c}" name = "packed">
   </lightning:input>

    <div>
        <lightning:button label="Packed!" onclick="{!c.packItem}"/>
   </div>
</aura:component>
```

campingListItemController.js

```
({
    packItem: function(component, event, helper)
    {
        component.get("{!v.Packed}") = true;
        event.getSource().set("v.disabled", true); 
    },
})
```

The button disable works though.

Perhaps the code isn't meant to run but I get this message when I try to complete the challenge:

> The campingListItem JavaScript controller isn't using 'component.set' to set the 'v.item' correctly to disable it.

when running this controller:

```
({
    packItem: function(component, event, helper)
    {
        console.log("clicked");
        component.set("v.item.Packed__c", true);
        event.getSource().set("v.disabled", true); 
    },
})
```

Comment: How is this question too broad? It's very specific and has plenty of detail, the answer I discovered shows that it's even more specific as you need to solve the challenge in the way that Salesforce wants you to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that to complete the challenge you need to do it in the way that they want. Also you do not need it to be runnable.

Create another attribute and use that to set the button to disabled instead of disabling it directly and it will pass.

Controller:

```
({
    packItem: function(component, event, helper)
    {
        let item = component.get("v.item");
        item.Packed__c = true;
        component.set("v.item", item);
        component.set("v.disabled", true)
    },
})
```

Component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" required="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <p>{!v.item.Name}</p>
    <p>{!v.item.Packed__c}</p>
    <p>  
        <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Price__c}" style="currency"/>
    </p>
    <p>  
        <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}"/>
    </p>

    <lightning:input type="toggle" 
                     label="Packed?" 
                     checked="{!v.item.Packed__c}" 
                     name="packed">
    </lightning:input>

    <div>
        <lightning:button label="Packed!" onclick="{!c.packItem}" disabled="{!v.disabled}"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: You will get Internal server error because there is no default value defined. Add this default="{Name:'Testing', Price__c:100, Quantity__c:1, Packed__c:false}"